# Change default highlight colour for textbox

Tags: vb.net

How can I change the highlight colour for a textbox from the default colour like in this pic "http://cdn.top4top.net/i_22a3fd3da51.png" to another colour?

Comment: yes :(
can you help ??

Comment: yes i can how can i do it for the RichTextBox @Rubik

Comment: Nope, sorry, wrong direction...

Comment: IIRC this is part of the system theme.

Comment: No but you can change the normal background colour. But I agree with IIRC